# Code Does Not "Finish" in system.Threading.Tasks.Task Method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I call a system.Threading.Tasks.Task method with .Wait() from Main. The method has a return statement at the end which I would hope denotes that the task has "finished", allowing Main to continue execution. However, the return statement is hit (debugged with breakpoint) but execution does not continue in Main but instead seems to just "hang", with no further execution happening.

Code is here.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses;
using Google.Apis.Dfareporting.v1_3;
using Google.Apis.Dfareporting.v1_3.Data;
using _file = Google.Apis.Dfareporting.v1_3.Data.File;
using Google.Apis.Download;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace DCMReportRetriever
{
    public class DCMReportRetriever
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            new DCMReportRetriever().Run().Wait();
            return; // This statement is never executed
        }

        private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run()
        {

            ...

            foreach (_file f in files)
            {
                if (f.Status == "REPORT_AVAILABLE" && f.LastModifiedTime >= startDateSinceEpoch)
                {
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(f.FileName + ".csv", FileMode.Append))
                    {
                        new MediaDownloader(service).Download(f.Urls.ApiUrl, stream);
                    }
                }
            }
            return; // This statement is hit (debugged with breakpoint)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I should add that Main is my entry point and apparently static async void Main is bad?

Comment: Please show the part of code which invokes `Run`.

Comment: First of all that return statement is redundant. Second: post a short but complete program which can reproduce the problem. Refer [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake with deadlock via context switching by async/await state machine.

You can find a clearly explained here:

[Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (Stephen Cleary)

> > **What Causes the Deadlock**
> >     Here’s the situation: remember from my intro post that after you await a Task, when the method continues it will continue in a context.
> >
> > In the first case, this context is a UI context (which applies to any UI except Console applications). In the second case, this context is an ASP.NET request context.
> >
> > One other important point: an ASP.NET request context is not tied to a specific thread (like the UI context is), but it does only allow one thread in at a time. This interesting aspect is not officially documented anywhere AFAIK, but it is mentioned in my MSDN article about SynchronizationContext.
> >
> > So this is what happens, starting with the top-level method (Button1_Click for UI / MyController.Get for ASP.NET):
> >
> > 1. The top-level method calls GetJsonAsync (within the UI/ASP.NET context).
> > 2. GetJsonAsync starts the REST request by calling HttpClient.GetStringAsync (still within the context).
> > 3. GetStringAsync returns an uncompleted Task, indicating the REST request is not complete.
> > 4. GetJsonAsync awaits the Task returned by GetStringAsync. The context is captured and will be used to continue running the GetJsonAsync method later. GetJsonAsync returns an uncompleted Task, indicating that the GetJsonAsync method is not complete.
> > 5. The top-level method synchronously blocks on the Task returned by GetJsonAsync. This blocks the context thread.
> > 6. … Eventually, the REST request will complete. This completes the Task that was returned by GetStringAsync.
> > 7. The continuation for GetJsonAsync is now ready to run, and it waits for the context to be available so it can execute in the context.
> > 8. Deadlock. The top-level method is blocking the context thread, waiting for GetJsonAsync to complete, and GetJsonAsync is waiting for the context to be free so it can complete.
> >
> > For the UI example, the “context” is the UI context; for the ASP.NET example, the “context” is the ASP.NET request context. This type of deadlock can be caused for either “context”.
> >
> > **Preventing the Deadlock**
> >     There are two best practices (both covered in my intro post) that avoid this situation:
> >
> > - In your “library” async methods, use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever possible.
> > - Don’t block on Tasks; use async all the way down.

switch this code:

```
new DCMReportRetriever().Run().Wait();
```

to async analog:

```
await new DCMReportRetriever().Run();
```

or even this:

```
await new DCMReportRetriever().Run().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, the .NET Framework doesn't allow the `Main` method to be async, so you need to add the "proxy" method to your app, something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    MyMethodAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    await new DCMReportRetriever().Run().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
}

private async Task Run()
{

    ...

    foreach (_file f in files)
    {
        if (f.Status == "REPORT_AVAILABLE" && f.LastModifiedTime >= startDateSinceEpoch)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(f.FileName + ".csv", FileMode.Append))
            {
                new MediaDownloader(service).Download(f.Urls.ApiUrl, stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more explanations in this article:

[Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: OP says return statement is hit in breakpoint. If that's true, your answer is irrelevant. Otherwise, OP should consider this answer.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the first breakpoint is hit, and after that the deadlock arises.

Comment: I don't understand what your comment mean. How can a deadlock happen after the annotated return statement is hit in OP's question?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Please read the full article I've linked. This is a common scenario with using `Wait()` method on async method, deadlock is happening into the state machine inside the .NET Core.

Comment: I've read that article way long back. I don't need to read it again. I recommend you read the question carefully. OP says return statement is hit(in breakpoint). If that is true then there is no way that code could deadlock. Either OP is wrong about that information or your answer is irrelevant. Edit: FWIW I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Updated the answer with full explanation what is going on.

Comment: Thanks very much. However, an important detail I should have noted which I've now added is that Main is my static (void) entry point and so probably shouldn't be async?

Comment: @adamcunnington Yes, it shouldn't be, and, actually, it can't be async. Updated the answer.

Comment: Hi VMAtm, that won't work because you can't use await in Main. I think the solution might be this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html?

Comment: @adamcunnington In other articles of Stephen he uses `.Wait()` method on the top.

Comment: The question shows a console program, which is specifically excluded by Cleary's description (as well as the possibility of this type of deadlock generally). Unless you have reason to believe that the OP is dealing with ASP.NET (nothing in his post suggests he is), your answer is completely inapplicable.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Not only the ASP.NET, but WinForms and WPF programs too, as they are single threaded too!

Comment: @VMAtm: yes, I understand that ("single-threaded" is not the right terminology, but whatever...I know what you mean). The point is that Cleary's article lists two scenarios in which his comments are applicable: `#1` when dealing with a UI context (which specifically does _not_ apply in the console application scenario), and `#2` in ASP.NET. The OP's question does not pertain to either #1 or #2, and being a console program is _specifically_ excluded from #1 (but also a plain console program is excluded from #2 as well, of course)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Can't see any evidence that the OP has the console program. And the behaviour of the OP "freeze" is very similar to the deadlock Cleary mentioned. Hope OP'll soon get back here and provide a resulting solution for his investigation.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Hmm, OP is creating the new instance of his program. I think this is the real problem! Tomorrow will check it for sure.

Comment: "Can't see any evidence that the OP has the console program" -- You mean besides the statement in his question that "I should add that Main is my entry point and apparently static async void Main is bad?" That seems like a pretty clear statement to me. What about it is confusing you?

Comment: "OP is creating the new instance of his program. I think this is the real problem!" -- creating an instance of the class isn't going to deadlock, or lead to it later somehow.

Comment: @PeterDuniho There is a famous problem with task await in static constructor. May be, here it is too. About the console - Main method is only an entry point. It may be console, WPF, WinForms, etc.

Comment: Yes, there is a famous problem with thread synchronization in general used in a static constructor. But there's no static constructor here. As far as the entry point goes, there's no `[STAThread]` on the entry point, and the issue reported exists _in that method_. Even if we generously assume on your behalf that somewhere else in the program, the OP is creating a new thread to run his Winforms/WPF UI, that would not have an effect on the code he's shown.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. In the end, I realised that I could get out of using async/await altogether which given I don't really understand asynchronous programming in C# properly, is probably wise!